# finiteness of an abelian topological group

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, abelian-groups, topological-groups, profinite-groups

Let A be an abelian (Hausdorff) topological group. Assume that

(1) the set of its torsion elements, and

(2) a finitely generated subgroup

are dense subsets of A.

**My question**: must A be finite?

(This is clearly true if A is discrete or if the f.g. subgroup is torsion).

**EDIT.** I'm more interested in compact groups.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider $S^1$, the multiplicative group of complex numbers of absolute value $1$.
The torsion elements are roots of unity, which are dense in $S^1$. Also the subgroup generated by any non-torsion element, say $\exp(2\pi it)$ with $t$ irrationals, is dense in $S^1$.

Of course, $S^1$ is compact and infinite.

Comment: Thanks! I should have thought about it. ...
A friend of mine (years ahead in math) told me that I knew a counterexample but I should look at totally disconnected groups. Do you know if my question is true for t.d. groups?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken the product of Z/pZ over p answers it negatively.